# Rotation matrix from non-unit axis and a general angle

Tags: geometry

I know the [explicit matrix of a proper rotation R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) by angle $\theta$ around the unit axis vector, $u = (u_x, u_y, u_z)$. I am curious to know the general matrix of proper rotation when $u$ is not the unit vector, I mean say $u_x^2 + u_y^2 + u_z^2 = R^2$?

Comment: Just normalize the given vector and use the same formula

Comment: Sorry, but will it be possible to provide some more details.?

Comment: Given a vector $v = (v_x, v_y, v_z)$, normalize it into vector $u = (u_x, u_y, u_z) =  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2}} (v_x, v_y, v_z) $ and use vector $u$ in the equation given in your reference.